C#: How to call methods from class libraries and printing them into console projects?
I am new to C# and I am learning how to pass values between class libraries and console apps.
Currently I have a 2 project set up in separate sub-folders. Where:
main-->lib --> classlib.cs
main-->src -->console.cs
Furthermore classlib.cs is set up like this:
namespace lib;

public class Passing
{
    public int being_passed = 4; 
}

While in console.cs :
using lib;

Console.Writeline(lib.Passing.being_passed.ToString());

For some reason my console.cs is not able to recognize my classlib.cs.(ie. it lists that the lib namespace has not been recognized) Even after adding a project reference in console.cs via the command dotnet add reference {path to classlib.csproj file here}.

You have declared an instance field. You are trying to access it as a static field.

"not able to recognize" - What is the exact error?

You attempt to access being_passed as if it was a static field of class Passing. But it isn't.
You need to have an instance of class Passing in order to access the non-static field being_passed:
// create an instance:
lib.Passing passingInstance = new lib.Passing();           

// access the field:
Console.Writeline(passingInstance.being_passed.ToString()); 

Alternatively, you can make the field static in the library (and then access it the way you attempted, since a static field does not require an instance):
public class Passing
{
//--vvvvvv----------------------------
    static public int being_passed = 4; 
}


Thank you! I had forgotten to initialize it.
